# Unknown format type for attachment while sending email from android app using javaMail Api

Tags: android, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to develop an app which contains a screen to upload a job seeker resume.As i can see the email with the attached document is delivered to the **'To'** mail Id but the document type is specified as **'unknown file type format'**.And other thing is since i am using the feature  provided by Google Mail ,the email is delivered in the name of registered email Id but not the Visitors mail Id.Following is the code i have written to send an email.Please help me out.Thanks in Advance.

```
  System.out.println("TLSEmail Start");

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            //  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

            //create Authenticator object to pass in Session.getInstance argument
            Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
                //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, "wpndththyxgofpmt");
                }
            };
          Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("ayyapparushi@gmail.com"));
            message.addRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));

            System.out.println("Mail Check 2");

            message.setSubject(al_JobsList.get(Position).getJobName() + "-" + al_JobsList.get(Position).getJobExp());

            System.out.println("Mail Check 3");
            BodyPart messageBodyPart;
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            messageBodyPart.setContent(messagepart, "text/html");
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

              messageBodyPart=new MimeBodyPart();

              message.setText(messagepart2);


             //  Transport.send(message);


               String file = emailmsg;
               String fileName = name + " resume";
               FileDataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
               messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
               // messageBodyPart.attachFile(file);
               messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
               multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
               // multipart.addBodyPart(message);

               message.setContent(multipart);
               Transport.send(message);
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my question on unsupported file format for the attachments when email is delivered to the user.While selecting up the file from the file explorer in mobile,the path is obtained but the file extension is not obtained.Hence,while giving the file name we need to append the extension of the file attached.Thus,When delivered Google automatically checks the file format.

```
    String fileName = name + " resume"+".docx";
```

This line solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Start by cleaning up these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Make sure you're using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#JavaMail_for_Android).

JavaMail (actually, JAF) only knows about a few file types.  You'll likely need to specify the MIME type for other types of files.  Use the [MimeBodyPart.attachFile method that allows you to specify the type](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Using Gmail (or almost any other email provider), you can't send the message as some arbitrary user.  You can only send the message as the owner of the account.